# Multiple CORS origins. Should I use if statement? - NginX

Tags: nginx, cors

I have set up an NginX in order to serve some static files from an instance.

The static files are to be used by 3 different domains that I own.

The NginX server is on its own (4th) domain. I want to restrict access to my files and apply a CORS policy.

I have researched as to how this can be achieved and I did manage to do it. In my location block I have tested the following code:

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:3000';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
```

The `http://localhost:3000` is for test purposes. I am currently trying to implement the same logic but only allow 3 specific, predefined domains. I found a possible solution which suggested that I use the following code snippet:

```
if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://example\.domain\.com$" ) {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $http_origin;
}
```

I'm guessing since NginX does not support if-elif-else syntax, that I can get away with it by using 3 if statements. However, I know that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) and that I there can be [unexpected behavior](http://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html) if some things are not taken into consideration.

I am relatively new to NginX so my question is, is the 3-if approach safe and reliable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, where you think of using `if` with nginx, it is much better to use `map` instead.

In this case you would create a `map` stating all allowed origins:

```
map $http_origin $origin_allowed {
   default 0;
   https://foo.example.com 1;
   https://bar.example.com 1;
   # ... add more allowed origins here
}
```

Note that there are *no* nested `if`s. So this won't work:

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    if ($origin_allowed = 1) { 
         ...
```

Putting `map` in further use and accounting for the fact that `add_header` will not be sending anything if the value is empty, you can have something that works:

```
map $http_origin $origin_allowed {
   default 0;
   https://foo.example.com 1;
   https://bar.example.com 1;
   # ... add more allowed origins here
}

map $origin_allowed $origin {
   default "";
   1 $http_origin;
}

if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $origin; 
   ...
```

The special `$origin` variable will contain one of our allowed origins, or if not matched, will be empty. When `add_header` is invoked with empty value, the header won't be sent. Thus it will be sent only for allowed origins.

Comment: That did the trick! I was not aware of the map module, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Danilla, but when I used it, it says `nginx: [emerg] unknown "origin" variable` :(